# RACObserve in RAC 4

Tags: reactive-cocoa-4

I am woking on a new new swift 2 project using ReactiveCocoa4 and I am wondering how to observe a property change like I dit it before in ObjC.

[RACObserve(self,self.model.wifiState) subscribeNext:^(id newValue){
        @strongify(self);
        self.wifiState = newValue;
    }];

Do you have any hint?

Thanks

Thierry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same using [`DynamicProperty`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoa/Swift/Property.swift#L180):

```
DynamicProperty(object: self.model, keyPath: "wifiState")
    .signal // or `producer` if you care about the current value
    .map { $0 as! WifiState } // Necessary because there is no way to infer the type of the given keyPath.
    .observeNext { [unowned self] self.wifiState = $0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need observe data (no UI) when use MutablePropery,
but if you need observe (or binding) UI so DynamicProperty

I write simple app use RAC4 for demonstration answer on more difficult after RAC2

[repo github link](https://github.com/ajjnix/RSS_Reader_ReactiveCocoa4)